# Python Printing Multiple Items- Web Scraping with XPath

Tags: python, pandas, function, xpath, web-scraping

I am very novice to Python and programming in general so please forgive my lack of insight. I  have managed to web-scrape some data with Xpath.

```
#Dependencies 
from lxml import html
import requests

#URL 
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20171004082203/https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/air-conditioning-service-repair'

#Use Requests to retrieve html 
resp = requests.get(url) 

#Create Tree from Request Response 
tree = html.fromstring(resp.content) 

#Create Tree element
elements = tree.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"lid-")]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]') 
# Scrape for URL and split for just business url
websites= (elements[0].attrib['href'].split("http://")[1])
```

The output of this code returns a single website url. However, I would like to print all the business urls to eventually put to a Pandas data frame.

How can I retrieve elements[0],elements[1],elements[2]... in one variable or expression?

I am sure there is an iterative function or list comprehension for this but I cannot wrap my brain around it. I'm thinking something like this:

Can I create a function to iterate through the 'elements[0]' and return all my values?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You need to have everything from the 'elements' list concatenated into a single value and stored in one variable? I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: Within the websites variable, I need all values of elements[x+1] to print. I am trying to retrieve all the urls from the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix that will get the websites from this particular site working from your code; it stores them all in the 'websites' list. That said if you're working on a webscraper you'd probably be better served working with [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
#Create Tree element
elements = tree.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"lid-")]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]') 

websites = []
for element in elements:
    try:
        websites.append("http"+element.attrib['href'].split("http")[2])
    except:
        continue
    
for website in websites:
    print(website, '\n')
```